# AppleScript won't go beyond top level

Tags: curl, applescript, applescript-numbers

I've found a script for downloading information about crypto currencies so that I can download into a Numbers spreadsheet using AppleScript. This is the script:

```
set mySheetName to "Coin Prices"
set myTableName to "Coin Prices"
set tgtCell to "A2"

set theHtml to do shell script "curl -s " & quoted form of "https://www.worldcoinindex.com"
set text item delimiters to {"<tbody>", "</tbody>"}
set tableContents to theHtml's text item 2 # item 2 is the body of the price table
set text item delimiters to {"<h2>"} # site uses new h2 for each currency
set tableChunks to tableContents's text items 2 thru -1
set pasteStr to ""
repeat with aChunk in tableChunks
    set text item delimiters to "><span>$ </span><span class=\"span\">"
    tell aChunk's text item 1 to set {theSymbol, thePrice} to {first word, last word}
    set pasteStr to pasteStr & theSymbol & tab & thePrice & return
end repeat
set the clipboard to pasteStr


tell application "Numbers"
    tell front document
        tell sheet mySheetName to tell table myTableName
            
            activate
            set selection range to range tgtCell
            delay 0.3
            tell application "System Events" to keystroke "v" using {option down, shift down, command down}
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

It works perfectly until I set this line:

```
set theHtml to do shell script "curl -s " & quoted form of "https://www.worldcoinindex.com/watchlist"
```

I've checked the webpage code and it's exactly the same but I get a big long error box with something to do with Item 2. I won't copy and paste because the error box contains the entire source code for the webpage. The error reads like this though:

> Can’t get text item 2 of

From there it's the source code.

Why does this script work on the base of the URL and not subdirectories of the URL?

Thanks for your help folks.

Comment: I don't see any `<tbody>` tags in the source for `https://www.worldcoinindex.com/watchlist`.

Comment: When I do a search for tbody it gives me two hits. An opening and closing tag. Do you have any currencies listed? It probably won't show up if you don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I do not have an account to access `https://www.worldcoinindex.com/watchlist` and see it *source code* while logged in, I'll take your word that it has the `<tbody>` and `</tbody>` *tags* and offer you an alternate solution to using `curl`.

Assuming you are using **Safari** and are logged in at the target **URL** and the *page* is fully loaded, you can use the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* to get the *data* you seek.

Add the following to the top of your existing **AppleScript** *script* while commenting out the `set theHtml to do shell script ...` line of *code*.

```applescript
tell application "Safari" to ¬
    set theHtml to do JavaScript ¬
        "document.getElementById('myTable').innerHTML;" in document 1
```

Note that `myTable` in the **JavaScript** *command* comes from the *table* on the main domain and may need to be adjusted for the **Watchlist**.

Look at the *page source* for e.g:

```html
<table id="myTable" class= ... >
<thead>
```

You can also use e.g.:

```applescript
"document.getElementsByClassName('...')[0].innerHTML;"in document 1
```

Replacing the `...` as shown in the *source code* for `class=`

---

**Update:**

Here is a version of *example* **AppleScript** *code* that will open a new **Safari** *document* to the target **URL**, and then dynamically create a **Numbers** *document* in the background, bring it frontmost once complete. No using `curl` or parsing **HTML** in a manner it really shouldn't be done in the first place. No clipboard or pasting into **Numbers**.

Note that the **Safari** *window* can stay the background once its `id` has been ascertained, which only takes a moment once the *window* first appears, you can then set focus elsewhere while the *script* runs. The new **Safari** *window* is actually already in the background when it's created as **Safari** has not been told to `activate`.

I created a *login* for the site and added the top three *coins* to my *watchlist*, and this screenshot is of the dynamically created **Numbers** *document*. It will do the same for the main **URL** as well if that's what you set `theURL` to in the *example* **AppleScript** *code*.

Note that as currently coded, if not logged in it will notify you and abort the running of the *script*. I hope to update the *code* a bit later to handle not being logged in and dynamically logging in if not, but that is for the next iteration of the *example* **AppleScript** *code*.

[image]

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
property theURL : "https://www.worldcoinindex.com/watchlist"
-- property theURL : "https://www.worldcoinindex.com"

property myNumbersSheetName : "Coin Prices"
property myNumbersTableName : "Coin Prices"


--  # Do not modify code below unless necessary.

property winID : missing value
property itemCount : missing value
property loginStatus : missing value
property thisNumbersDocument : missing value
property theNumbersDocumentName : missing value
property theSafariDocumentName : missing value

--  # Create a new Safari document to the target URL.
--  # Get the id of the newly created window.
--  # Wait for the page to finish loading.
--  # Get the name of the newly created document.
--  # Get Login status and if not already logged in,
--  # notify user and abort the running of the script.
--  # Get the count of ticker symbols for Numbers.

tell application "Safari"
    make new document with properties {URL:theURL}
    set winID to id of window 1
    my waitForSafariPageToFinishLoading()
    set theSafariDocumentName to name of window id winID
    tell document theSafariDocumentName
        set loginStatus to ¬
            do JavaScript ¬
                "document.getElementsByClassName('logout-nav-container')[0].innerHTML;"
        if loginStatus contains "Login" then
            display dialog ¬
                "You are not logged in!   Please login, " & ¬
                "then run script again..." buttons {"OK"} ¬
                default button 1 with title ¬
                "Login Required To Run This Script"
            return
        else
            set itemCount to my getTickerSymbolCount()
        end if
    end tell
end tell


--  # Create a new document in Numbers in the background.
--  # Create two columns and one row more than the number of
--  # ticker symbols on the page. Set the column header names.

tell application "Numbers"
    set columnCount to 2
    set rowCount to itemCount + 1
    set thisNumbersDocument to make new document
    set theNumbersDocumentName to the name of thisNumbersDocument
    tell thisNumbersDocument
        delete every table of every sheet
        tell active sheet to set its name to myNumbersSheetName
        tell sheet myNumbersSheetName
            set thisTable to ¬
                make new table with properties ¬
                    {name:myNumbersTableName ¬
                        , column count:columnCount ¬
                        , row count:rowCount}
            tell thisTable
                set value of cell "A1" to "Ticker Symbol"
                set value of cell "B1" to "Last Price"
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end tell


--  # Get the 'Ticker Symbol' and 'Last Price' for 
--  # the number of symbols on the page, setting their 
--  # values to the target cells in the Numbers document.

tell application "Safari"
    tell document theSafariDocumentName
        set n to 2
        repeat with i from 0 to itemCount - 1
            set |Ticker Symbol| to ¬
                first paragraph of ¬
                (do JavaScript ¬
                    "document.getElementsByClassName('ticker')[" & i & "].innerText;")
            my addToNumbersTable("A", n, |Ticker Symbol|)
            set |Last Price| to ¬
                (do JavaScript ¬
                    "document.getElementsByClassName('number pricekoers lastprice')[" & i & "].innerText;")
            my addToNumbersTable("B", n, |Last Price|)
            set n to n + 1
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell


-- # Set focus to cell A1 and bring 
-- # the Numbers document frontmost.

tell application "Numbers"
    --  # Set focus to cell A1.
    tell table myNumbersTableName of ¬
        sheet myNumbersSheetName of ¬
        document theNumbersDocumentName to ¬
        set selection range to range "A1"
    activate
end tell



--  ##  Handlers  ##

to getTickerSymbolCount()
    tell application "Safari" to ¬
        tell document ¬
            theSafariDocumentName to ¬
            return ¬
                (do JavaScript ¬
                    "document.getElementsByClassName('ticker').length;") ¬
                    as integer
end getTickerSymbolCount

to addToNumbersTable(c, n, v)
    --  # Sets the value of the target cell.    
    tell application "Numbers" to ¬
        tell table myNumbersTableName of ¬
            sheet myNumbersSheetName of ¬
            document theNumbersDocumentName to ¬
            set value of cell (c & n) to v
end addToNumbersTable

on waitForSafariPageToFinishLoading()
    --  # Wait for page to finish loading in Safari.
    --  # This works in **macOS Catalina** (10.15.7) and 
    --  # macOS Big Sur (11.4) and may need adjusting for
    --  # updated versions of Safari in these version of 
    --  # macOS, or other versions of macOS past or future.
    tell application "System Events" to repeat until ¬
        exists (buttons of groups of toolbar 1 of window 1 of ¬
            process "Safari" whose name = "Reload this page")
        delay 0.5
    end repeat
end waitForSafariPageToFinishLoading
```

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment:  That is magic. It worked perfectly. I guess it means I have to have that page open and logged in. So I found this script to open the correct tab in Safari:  

`do shell script "open -a \"Safari\" \"" & "https://www.worldcoinindex.com/watchlist" & "\""`

Comment: @Loweded Wookie, I'd use `tell application "Safari" to make new document with properties {URL:"https://www.worldcoinindex.com/watchlist"}` instead of the `do shell script` _command_ to open the **URL**.

Comment: @Loweded Wookie, RE: "I guess it means I have to have that page open and logged in." --  Yes, but your weren't getting the _data_ with the `curl_` _command_ and why I offered this as an alternative. I'm pretty sure that the whole process could be coded to be non-interactive.  In other words, if the login credential can be saved, or even programmatically input, the _script_ could run from start to finish with you only having the run it.

Comment: Weird, It's stopped working now with the error message  The variable theHtml is not defined.

Comment: It seems it doesn't like the `tell application "Safari" to ¬
    set theHtml to do JavaScript ¬
        "document.getElementById('myTable').innerHTML;" in document 1` method. I reverted back to the do script method and it works fine. I'll stick with this for the time being.

Comment: @Loweded Wookie, You'll get the error 'error "The variable theHtml is not defined."' if the frontmost **Safari** page is not on the target **URL**.

Comment: It should be though because I made that `tell` code the first line in the list. It definitely creates the page in Safari but for some reason the setting of "theHtml" doesn't reference it. Is there a way to force Safari to use that new window as active?

Comment: @Loweded Wookie, I'll probably create a login so I can _script_ both **URL**s and login automatically, assuming credentials can be save for the site. I'll have to do this tomorrow though. This way it could be saved as an **AppleScript** _application_ that could be fully automated and run in the background.

Comment: @Loweded Wookie, I have added to my answer some _example_ **AppleScript** _code_ that will dynamically create the **Numbers** _document_ in the background with the **Safari** _window_ being in the background too. Please give it a try and let me know if it works for you, thanks.

Comment: Sorry, been tied up lately. I can't seem to download that link. Do I need to have an account to be able to download it?

Comment: @Loweded Wookie, The link expired, but I already modified the answer to include what was in that link as mentioned in the comment directly before your previous comment. Please give it a try and let me know if it works for you, thanks.

Comment: thanks, that script works wonders. When I get a chance I'll have a play with it and see if I can get it to work on a site that I prefer. This gives me exactly what I need though.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that the main page contains an explicit html table, while the watchlist page seems to be a structured series of div elements generated by javascript and made to look like a table. There is no 'tbody' element on the watchlist page because there is no table there. The text items command splits the first page into three parts (the second of which is the one you want); it doesn't split the watchlist page at all, which produces an array with a single item containing all of the html. When you ask an array of 1 element for its second item, you get your error.

You're going to have to examine the html of the second page and figure out how to split the text to extract the information you want.

Comment: There's definitely a tbody on the page I'm looking at.

I'm starting to think I might know what the problem is. When I'm using Safari I'm seeing the information I want because I'm logged in. However, when I run the script I'm not.

The problem is that if I use the home page I can't see the coins I specifically want. I also only see 100 of the 500 or so coins available on the site.

Comment: @LowededWookie: I'm looking at the page in question as we speak, and there is no tbody element anywhere. Of course, I'm not logged in (I don't even have an account), so maybe you're right that this is the problem. I'm afraid I'm not much of a curl expert, but I'm sure you could expand the curl command to use a login name and password, or a certificate (not sure how this site handles logins). You'd probably need to talk to a site manager there to get the details.

Comment: Of course, there is no tbody element anywhere, because the content of indicated webpage is single image and not a text.

Comment: With an account you can set a bunch of coins to keep an eye on. When there are coins on the page there is definitely, 100% a tbody.